# C# Question About Delete Data Grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have binded a data grid to an array. Also, there is a button there to delete the row. The problem is that I am not sure how to implement it since the data source is an array.

See below

```
  <Columns>    
     <asp:TemplateColumn>        
            <ItemTemplate>          
       <asp:Label ID="lblItems" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem>' />         
       </ItemTemplate>    
     </asp:TemplateColumn>     
        <asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete">
          </asp:ButtonColumn>
                 </Columns>
```

and here I would like to implement it..

```
   private void DataGrid1_DeleteCommand(object source,
                  System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowToDelete = e.Item.ItemIndex;

        myDataGrid.DataBind();
    }
```

In the code for the deletion, how can I access the index of my array based on the button clicked (per row)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example

Markup.

```
<asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        OnDeleteCommand="DataGrid1_DeleteCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblItems" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>'>
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateColumn>
        <asp:ButtonColumn ButtonType="PushButton" 
                CommandName="Delete" 
                HeaderText="Actions" 
                Text="Delete">
        </asp:ButtonColumn>
    </Columns>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Code-behind.

```
private static string[] names = new string[] { "Matt", "Joanne", "Robert" };
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}
private void BindGrid()
{
    DataGrid1.DataSource = names;
    DataGrid1.DataBind();
}
protected void DataGrid1_DeleteCommand(object source, DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string deletedItem = ((Label) DataGrid1.Items[e.Item.ItemIndex].FindControl("lblItems")).Text;
    names = names.Where(val => val != deletedItem).ToArray();
    BindGrid();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to access your src object using the method below (notice this is 'RowDeleting' event on gridview)?

```
    protected void gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        MyObject o = (MyObject)gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataItem;
    }
```

There are also other tricks like storing an id in a hiddenfield on the row and then on the delete command you search for the control and pluck your value.  My preference is the method above but really depends on what your goal is.

```
    protected void gv_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        HiddenField field = (HiddenField)gv.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("myHiddenField");
        string myValue = field.Value;

        // delete it and rebind
    }
```